# How does the split method calculating the array

Tags: java, string, split

I have this program

```
    String s = "aa";
    String[] tokens = s.split("a");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);
```

It will print `0`

Now when I change the String s to `"aa aaaa"` this will only print **3** but why?? is it supposed to be 6?

And when I add space after the it `"aa aaaa "` it will print 7 which is expected value to be.

So why is the split method behaving like this?

Comment: Have you started by reading the javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documention of the `split method` is saying:

```
 Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
```

(Trailing empty strings) can also refer to the **regex** you give which is in your example: `a`, means all trailing
`a` wont be in the resulting array.

So lets look how it is splitted

```
"aa"
```

will print 0 because it is a trailing a

```
"aa a"
```

will print 3

now by the time you add space it wont be `a` trailing a anymore, the string will now be splitted 
between `a` starting from the first index to the known trailing `a`.

```
"aa aaaa"
```

still print 3 because `aaaa` is a trailing `a`

```
"aa aaaa "
```

will print 7

now again it not a trailing `a` anymore therefor it will be splitted between `a's`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

`Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.`

Example:-

The string `boo:and:foo`, for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

`Regex   Result
:        { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o        { "b", "", ":and:f" }`

Hence all the trailing `a` will be discarded . To do a full split returning each individual element:-

```
    String s = "aa";
    String[] tokens = s.split("");
    System.out.println(tokens.length); //this will output 3 :- "","a","a"
```